# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract.................. in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, endpoint

I have created a WCF service and Web.Config file has below settings.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" sendTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Axis.OptimizationService.RMSCalculationService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Axis.RMS.Optimization.Contracts.IRMSCalculationService"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
```

In my ClassLibrary project, I have created Servcie reference with the name CatpricingService and the app.config file looks as below.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRMSCalculationService" closeTimeout="00:30:00"
        openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
        maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:2200/RMSCalculationService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRMSCalculationService"
    contract="CatPricingService.IRMSCalculationService"  name="BasicHttpBinding_IRMSCalculationService" />
</client>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I did this several times. I could not figure out what the error is. To me all settings seems correct.
I am getting this error.

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'CatPricingService.IRMSCalculationService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

I referred other questions on Stackoverflow..... i m going nuts with this.
Can anyone figure out what is wrong with my settings?

Here my ClassLibrary project is running with external program excel.exe. (Project properties, Debug tab, selected "Start external program" and gave value as **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE**

Thanks

Comment: You mention app.config, this app.config is inside your ClassLibrary Project or in another project which reference your ClassLibrary?

Comment: This app.config file is in ClassLirary project only.

Comment: ok, so please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

You need to move the configuration from `app.config` in your `ClassLibrary` project to the `app.config` of the main project (for example, an WPF application). Probably it is the project which references your `ClassLibrary`.

Only `app.config` in the main project will be used when your program executes.

**Updated:**

In this case, I think you need to create client class programmatically, do not depend on `app.config`, something like this:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:2200/RMSCalculationService.svc");
var client = new YourGeneratedClientClass(binding, endPointAddress);
```

Comment: I have Excel.exe as external Start program. I updated that point in my question.

Comment: @Ritha, so you mean Excel.exe will consume your DLL?

Comment: I know it's been like 3 years, but thank you so much for that piece of code below your update. It really helped me. I have a C# class library project where everything is put correctly in app.config. Other (C++) projects in my solution use that class library, but don't have an app.config. The errormessage drove me nuts, especially since it all appears to be correctly configured...

Comment: I just wanted to reconfirm that adding new binding and endpoint solved the issue for me as well. The Client implementation came from a 3rd party - and while the Endpoint was reflected in the implementation it was not working. The moment I called a constructor with it, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by copying the app.config file by renaming to Excel.exe.config to this folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ . Since from there the Application is running it is looking for Config file at that location.